# test/training effect on classifers results

Tags: weka

im struggling to understand the effect of training/test data's effect on my correctly classified instances result.

An example with naive bayes if i apply more test data in percentage split the algorithm becomes more reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of splitting your entire data set into training and test is that the model you want to learn (naive Bayes or otherwise) should reflect the true relationship between cause and effect (features and prediction) and not simply the data. For example, you can always fit a curve perfectly to a number of data points, but doing that will likely make it useless for the prediction you were trying to make.

By using a separate test set, the learned model is tested on *unseen* data. Ideally, the error (or whatever you're measuring) on training and test set would be about the same, suggesting that your model is reasonably general and not *overfit* to the training data.

If in your case decreasing the size of the training set increases performance on the test set, it suggests that the learned model is too specific and cannot be generalised. Instead of changing the training/test split, you should tweak the parameters of your learner however. You might also want to consider using [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) instead of a simple training/test split as it will provide more reliable performance estimates.